# Une nuance entre « était censé » et « devait »

Tags: sens

> La biopuce **n'était pas censée** forcer les gens à faire quoi que ce soit ! Elle **devait** juste limiter leurs pouvoirs.

Je crois que « devait » indique ici une prévision ou une intention qui ne s'est pas réalisée, et est traduit en anglais par « was supposed to » ou « was due to ». Se pourrait-il donc que « devait » s'emploie tout comme « était censé » ?

Il se trouve que « censée » est également utilisé ici dans la phrase précédente. La question est alors de savoir si on peut substituer « devait » à « était censé » et inversement :

> La biopuce **ne devait pas** forcer les gens à faire quoi que ce soit ! Elle **était** juste **censée** limiter leurs pouvoirs.

Comment: [Être censé](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/cens%C3%A9) →   *be supposed to*. [Devoir](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/devoir) → *have to/ be to.*

Comment: +1 for making me feel less lonely in thinking that there might be an overlap between the two, although I do feel an overlap **primarily** when “devoir” is used conditionally and/or when one or the other of them is used negatively (& I invariably default to “should not [have] …” for them both). If there is a nuance (or more) between the two in the negative it would be whatever difference there is between “Nul ne doit ignorer [la loi]” and “Nul n’est censé ignorer [la loi], but I can’t help you with that because I don’t see any and therefore translate them both as “No one should ignore the law.”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utiliser **censé** sous-entend qu'une contrainte, règle ou état défini par le verbe qui suit n'ont pas été ou ne sont pas respectés. On emploie d'ailleurs rarement censé dans une phrase au futur sauf si l'on est déjà quasiment sûr que ce sera pas respecté.

---

- « La biopuce **n'était pas censée** forcer les gens » implique qu'en réalité, les gens ont quand même été forcés.
- « La biopuce **ne devait pas** forcer les gens » ne donne pas d'indication sur ce qui s'est effectivement passé. Les gens ont peut-être été forcés, mais peut-être pas.

  ---
- « J'**étais censé** être à Paris » implique que l'on était ailleurs alors que l'on aurait dû être à Paris.
- « Je **devais** être à Paris » ne présume rien, soit j'y étais car justement je devais y être, soit je n'y étais pas pour une raison quelconque.

  ---
- « Je **n'étais pas censé** être à Paris » implique que j'y étais quand même alors que je n'aurais pas dû.
- « Je **ne devais pas** être à Paris » peut être suivi de « mais j'y étais » ou de « et je n'y étais pas » voire même de « mais je ne m'en souviens plus très bien ».

---

- « Nul **n'est censé** ignorer la loi » est l'expression consacrée car l'on sait bien que ce n'est pas le cas.
- « Nul **ne doit** ignorer la loi » est plus ambitieux (ou naïf).

Answer (score 1):

[Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%AAtre_cens%C3%A9/14074) donne :

> Censé : considéré comme devant être ou devant faire quelque chose ; être supposé.

La différence entre « devoir » et « être censé » est maigre mais semble consister dans le fait que le deuxième exprime une sorte de supposition / connaissance populaire que le premier n'exprime pas forcément.

« Devoir » est plus certain que « être censé. »